# How to merge two numpy arrays with same number of rows but different number of columns

Tags: python

Given these two numpy arrays:

```
# Two 2-dim arrays with same row number but differnt column
a1 = np.array([[9,9,9,9], [9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9]], dtype=np.int64)
a2 = np.array([[3],[3],[3]], dtype=np.int64)
```

How would one merge these to arrays two create a third array like the following:

```
# Third array with same row numbers as above two arrays but its column number is the sum of column numbers of the above two arrays
[[9,9,9,9,3],
 [9,9,9,9,3],
 [9,9,9,9,3]]
```

**In simpler terms, how do you concatenate a column to a 2-dimensional array?**

Comment: `np.concatenate([a1,a2], 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

a1 = np.array([[9,9,9,9], [9,9,9,9],[9,9,9,9]])
a2 = np.array([[3],[3],[3]])
print(np.concatenate((a1, a2), axis=1))
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

`Join a sequence of arrays along an existing axis.`